# Who were the Hivites, mentioned at Genesis 34:2?

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible, canaan

The inhabitants of Shechem, who were slaughtered by Simeon and Levi in Genesis 34, are described as "Hivites." Who were they?

Answer (score 1):

The Hivites appear in just 25 verses, all in the OT, and all but six of the verses appear in the Pentateuch or Joshua. If you remove the verses in which they are mentioned in lists, we learn just one significant fact about them, as I will explain; but first, some other assorted facts.

- They are one of the original listed Canaanite tribes (Gen 10:17).
- Shechem, as we already know, was a Hivite city.
- One of Esau’s wives was a Hivite.
- They were to be driven out by the Israelites with the other Canaanites, despite being one of the “seven nations greater and mightier than thou” (Deut 7:1).

The more significant fact is this. It turns out that the Hivite nation included the inhabitants of Gibeon; readers of the book of Joshua might recall this as the city that tricked the Israelites into sparing them, during Joshua’s first invasion.

While we hear no more about the other Hivites, except that they were destroyed, we do read plenty more about the Gibeonites, who were essentially enslaved by the Hebrews as hewers of wood and carriers of water; they were, naturally, converted and incorporated among the Hebrews as proselytes. So it is interesting indeed the Shechemites were the first Hivites, indeed the first Canaanites, whom the Israelites put to the sword *en masse.*